# Web site error generates a Ruby on Rails error instead of the classical red error page in Rails 6.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling

I recently started with Rails 6.1 on Windows server. It runs as expected and shows Rails welcome screen. Including the Rails red page if I generate an error in the code.

Then I installed webpack, Yarn etc. and started copying some models from an old application I'd like to reuse. Since then any error in the code breaks Rails: instead of the expected red page, it drops hundreds of lines with the following errors repeated several times:

```
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionview-6.1.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:300: warning: __FILE__ in eval may not return location in binding; use Binding#source_location instead
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/web-console-3.7.0/lib/web_console/exception_mapper.rb:31: warning: in `eval'
```

And then another bloc:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 3)
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionview-6.1.4/lib/action_view/base.rb:230:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/web-console-3.7.0/lib/web_console/template.rb:21:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/web-console-3.7.0/lib/web_console/template.rb:21:in `render'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/web-console-3.7.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:37:in `block in call'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/web-console-3.7.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/web-console-3.7.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:24:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:98:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-4.3.0/lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:23:in `perform_request'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-proxy-0.7.0/lib/rack/proxy.rb:63:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:539:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/puma-5.4.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:249:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/puma-5.4.0/lib/puma/request.rb:77:in `block in handle_request'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/puma-5.4.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:340:in `with_force_shutdown'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/puma-5.4.0/lib/puma/request.rb:76:in `handle_request'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/puma-5.4.0/lib/puma/server.rb:440:in `process_client'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/puma-5.4.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:147:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

What did I break ?

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing what you added.  I'd walk back to your last working version and start adding things in one-by-one.

Comment: Looks like web-console gem is still on the previous major version. Since you use rails `6.1.4` My initial guess it that functionality changed and you should update the web-console gem version to a more recent version.

Comment: Yes, you are right ! This solved the issue ! Thanks !